# Adjust mysql database query to filter column value

Tags: php, mysql, database

This should be an easy one for folks who are knowledgeable about database queries (I just started to learn).

In my multiple author site, I use the following function to get the top 2 categories the user has publishing in:

```
// Function to get the user's top two categories
function GetTop2CategoryByUser($user_id, $taxonomy){
    global $wpdb;

    $results=$wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare(
        "
       SELECT      tt.term_id as category, COUNT(p.ID) as count
       FROM        $wpdb->posts p

       JOIN        $wpdb->term_relationships tr
                   ON p.ID = tr.object_id

       JOIN        $wpdb->term_taxonomy tt
                   ON tt.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id
                   AND (tt.taxonomy = %s AND tt.term_taxonomy_id != 1)

       WHERE       p.post_author = %s
       GROUP BY    tt.term_id
       ORDER BY    count DESC LIMIT 2
    ",
        $taxonomy,
        $user_id
    ) );
    return $results;
}
```

To my question: Under the `posts` table, I have the column `post_status` with value `published`. I want the query to only get results that have `post_status` set to `published`.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add into the  where

```
and p.post_status = 'published'
```